# Vue Component Not Displaying Nested Div

Tags: vue.js, vue-component

I have a component that works fine. However, when I appended `<div :id="hint"></div>` to the component this specific DIV isn't rendering. I'm sure it has something to do with the way I'm using a DIV to reference the template in my HTML but I don't know how to refine it.

```
<div
    ref="boxAnswers"
    is="box-answers"
    v-for="box in boxes.slice().reverse()"
    v-bind:key="box.id"
    v-bind:level="box.level"
    v-bind:hint="box.hint"
></div>


Vue.component('box-answers', {
    props: ['level','hint'],
    template: '<div class="droppable answer ui-widget-header" :id="level"></div><div :id="hint"></div>'
});


 new Vue({ 
  el: '#mainapp',
data: {
   boxes: [
        { id: 1, level: 'baselevel-1', hint: 'hint-1' },
        { id: 2, level: 'baselevel-2', hint: 'hint-2' },
        { id: 3, level: 'baselevel-3', hint: 'hint-3' },
        { id: 4, level: 'baselevel-4', hint: 'hint-4' },
        { id: 5, level: 'baselevel-5', hint: 'hint-5' }
    ]
}
  });
```

Comment: probably can't have two root elements

Comment: @AngrySpartan, I believe what @A.Lau is saying is in your `box-answers` component, you should try wrapping both `divs` in a parent `div`

Comment: I understand what you're saying but don't know how to convert that into code.